# How to prevent executing javascript code before data is entered in jquery dialog form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to develop reusable function based on a jQuery dialog form, as a replacement for JS prompt. I need user to input data before other JS code is executed (the AJAX request that follows depends on the input of the user).

The function should read one text field and return the value entered if OK button or Return are pressed.

I managed to create the function with callback and it is working, except it doesn't wait for the user to react and the code after the function is executed.

I understand that jQuery calls are asynchronous and tried versions with deferred option, but that didn't work either.

Is there any way to make my code wait for the user input before it continues executing? Of course, the ideal solution would be to use like `var userInput = getTxtField(....);`

**Update:**
The function `getTxtField` is triggered by other user actions (buttons): renameFile, renameFolder, addFile etc.

**Update #2 Problem solved**

Thanks to @SuperPrograman's suggestion I started thinking with the logic of asynchronous execution. The original code was developed with `value = prompt(...)` approach and the AJAX code was at the bottom of the single function. I simply took the AJAX code in a separate function and now it works as expected. I've updated the JS code at the bottom.

My code is the following

```
....
<div class='hidden' id='dialog-newName' title=''>
  <label id='label-txtField' for="txtField"></label>
  <input type="text" name="txtField" id="txtField" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
</div>        
....
function getTxtField (title, label, defVal, callBack) {
    $('#label-txtField').text(label);
    $('#txtField').val(defVal);
    $( '#dialog-newName' ).dialog({
        modal: true, closeOnEscape: false, 
        height: 200, width: 500,
        title: title, 
        buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                callBack('OK', $('#txtField').val());
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $('#txtField').val('');
                //callBack('Cancel', ''); // not necessary
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
    });
}
...
    switch (action) {
      case 'action1':
       // user pressed button for Action1
       console.log('before dialog getTxtField ');
       getTxtField('Action1', 'Label1', 'defaultValue1', function(buttonP, result) {
         console.log(buttonP + ' value=' + result); // prints OK
       });
      // executed before input finished
      console.log('after dialog getTxtField returnVal=' + newName + ')');
      break;
    case 'action2':
     // ....
     break;
    }
    // proceed with AJAX request for selected action
...
//=========================
// working code
//=========================
$('.selector').click ( function() {
  var frmId = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
  var action = $(this).attr('ajaxAction');
  var form = $('#theForm')[0];
  var ajaxData = new FormData(form);
  switch action {
    case 'actions that do not require function getTxtField':
      ajaxData.append(specific data for the action);
      ajaxCall (frmId, ajaxData);
      break;
    case 'actions that with function getTxtField':
      getTxtField('Titlexx', 'Labelxx', 'defaultValuexx', function(buttonP, result) {
        // process result
        ajaxData.append(specific data for the action);
        ajaxCall (frmId, ajaxData);
      });
      break;
  }
})

function ajaxCall (id, data) {
  // standard ajax code
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you might want to trigger the function on input change? https://api.jquery.com/change/  You can also put a check in the js change function so it will only fire if the input value is greater than e.g. 3 characters.

Comment: @dmikester1 I updated my question to clarify how the function is triggered. I believe now it's clear that I actually want a replacement for JS prompt! The code is working like that, I just wanted to avoid ugly browser implementations of prompt!

Comment: You'll just need to format code so everything that comes after dialog runs inside callback or initiated from the callback unless you do awful hacky sleeping

Comment: @SuperPrograman thanks for the comment. It helped great deal.
At first I didn't like the idea just because it didn't meet my initial expectations (solution similar to `var value = getTextFeild(....)` - apparently that it is not possible!?),  it made me think differently.
I was blinded with the initial code logic where the AJAX request was at the bottom and was executed after all input was checked.
I simply took the AJAX request out in a different function and make calls to it inside the callback.

Comment: @SuperPrograman would need to add a proper answer right below, in the Your Answer section. However, you can vote up his/her comment.

Comment: @ChrisTapay how do I vote up his/her comment?

Comment: simply click the up arrow next to the comment

Comment: @user3560520 you need at least 15 of reputation to upvote: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment helped, I'll add answer for quick access.
Basically you want to format code so everything that comes after dialog runs inside callback directly or is initiated from the callback.

So assuming a simple getTxtField prompt method taking a message and a callback function, instead of:

```
stuffBeforePrompt();
getTxtField('stuff', function() { });
stuffAfterPrompt();
```

You'll just need:

```
stuffBeforePrompt();
getTxtField('stuff', function() {
    stuffAfterPrompt();
});
```

Perhaps you could make some solution using 'threads' or workers where you run prompt on separate thread and sleep main until result (or vice versa); but I doubt that would be worth the slight usage convenience.